# Clarification in template declaration, alias and specialization in regards to custom allocators and stl

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-specialization, allocator

Sorry for the vague title, but I don't know exactly which is the correct term (and even if it's possible to do the following).

Let's say I have somewhere a template class (an allocator):

```
template<class Arena, typename T> Allocator
{
  public:
     Allocator(Arena a);
...
};
```

Then I have another class, which is in some kind of relation with `Allocator`, but can't specialize `T` param in instantiation.
The idea is declare a "not specialized alias" for it, and let the specialization be somewhere else.
Something like:

```
class MemoryArena
{
   using Allocator<T> = AnAllocatorStrategy<T>; //not legal, but just to give the idea

   void* Allocate(size_t);
};
```

The usage should be something like:

```
Arena anArena(...);
Arena::Allocator<int> allocInt; // some way declare a specialization of the alias

std::vector<int, Arena::Allocator<int>> myVec(allocInt);
```

The main idea behind that, is that because of `stl` container need a specialized allocator on the contained element's type, I can still use the same memory arena and let the specialized instances to forward the allocate call to it. 
But I still would like that is the Arena itself controlling the base allocation strategy (eventually also parametrazing the not completely specialized `AllocatorStrategy` ).

Any hint on this? Is this possible?

---

EDIT

Thanks to the comment I fixed the declaration using alias templates this way:

```
class MemoryArena
{
   template<typename T> using MyAllocatorTemplate = Allocator<MemoryArena, T>;;

  void* Allocate(size_t);
};
```

I still need to figure out if it's possible make `Allocator` be part of `MemoryArena` definition, without fully specify `T` parameter. Something like:

```
template<class AllocatorType<MemoryArena,?> = DefaultAllocType<MemoryArena,?>> //is possible not to specify T on MemoryArena definition?
class MemoryArena<AllocatorType>
{
   template<typename T> using MyAllocatorTemplate = AllocatorType<MemoryArena,T>;
```

Alternatively, any other suggestion is appreciated. The main goal is to let the user specify the Arena's allocator type except for the `T` parameter (useful only for using the allocator inside containers).

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your issue, but might alias templates help? `template<typename T> using MyAllocatorTemplate = Allocator<MyArena, T>;`

Comment: ah ok..thanks for the answer. I missed the term alias templates, I'll check by I think it's the syntax I was looking for.

Comment: @dyp: I updated the question. I hope is more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class...T0s>
struct partial_apply {
  template<class...T1s>
  using result = Z<T0s...,T1s...>;
};
template<template<class...>class A, template<class...>class B>
struct same_template : std::false_type {};
template<template<class...>class A>
struct same_template<A,A> : std::true_type {};

template<class...>class Default {};
template<
  template<class...>class AllocatorType=Default
>
class MemoryArena {
  template<class T>
  using MyAllocatorTemplate = std::conditional_t<
    same_template<AllocatorType, Default>{},
    DefaultAllocType<MemoryArena, T>,
    AllocatorType<T>
  >;
};
```

suppose there is some other alloc type besides `DefaultAllocType`, `OtherAllocType<Chicken, T>`.  Then:

```
template<class...Ts>
using OtherAllocChicken = partial_apply<OtherAllocType, Chicken>::template result<Ts...>;
using ChickenArena = MemoryArena< OtherAllocChicken >;
```

on the other hand, if you require that the argument passed to the incoming template be `MemoryArena` itself *sometimes*, things get more complex.

Before `MemoryArena` is parameterized, the type doesn't exist.  So you have to have some kind of placeholder that can tell you where you should inject it.

If you want it to always be `MemoryArena`, then things are easier: you already have that solution:

```
template<template<class...>class AllocatorType = DefaultAllocType>
class MemoryArena {
  template<typename T>
  using MyAllocatorTemplate = AllocatorType<MemoryArena,T>;
};
```

Comment: Yes, I just want it to be always MemoryArena. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @dyp I wasn't sure if it was going to cross the road.  Fixed.  Does make `partial_apply` pretty pointless.